# Do languages generally tend to avoid palindromic syllables?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, phonotactics

E.g. /knank stjajts smoms/ even they do follow the Sonority Sequencing Principle

Comment: At least some palindrome syllables are relatively common. For instance,  “stats”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several reasons conspiring to make palindromic syllables rare in natural languages

- Most languages have certain restrictions on the beginning and ending consonant clusters of syllables, and those restrictions are typically not symmetrical, i.e., in general a reversed syllable needn't be legal
- a diphthong at the syllable core cannot occur in a palindromic syllable
- there are also some consonants (e.g. affricates like /ts/ or /pf/) that cannot be reversed
- diachronic processes like dissimilation tend to get rid of double occurrences of the consonants /l, n, r/ in one syllable

Nevertheless, simple palindromic syllables occur and some frequent words (like English *a*, *did*) are examples of them.

Comment: Isn't assimilation also at work?

Comment: Assimilation usually affects neighbouring consonants, while dissimilation works over the syllable core. I don't think that assimilation does much to the probability of palindromes.

Comment: Perhaps also mention asymmetry with affricates; it is not unusual for e.g. */ts/* to be an affricate but */st/* to not be one.

Comment: I don't mean they can't be reversed; but the sound in *aufpassen* doesn't sound like the reverse of *Pfad;* and the one in *zucchini* doesn't sound and often isn't perceived as the reverse of the one in *bistro,* as even the Italian orthography indicates.

Comment: @tripleee Your comments made me curious to ask a new question on that: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/are-there-languages-featuring-reversed-affricates-as-phonologocal-segments

Comment: I thought there was also assimilation in single syllable words, where the onset primes for the final consonants, regardless of intervening vowel.  It is a force that we resist due to the usefulness of short words, but it does affect speech, encouraging: mom, dad, pop, tot, bub, etc.

Comment: @aml I don't see assimilation (of what precedent?) in words like mom or dad. They look like reduplication to me.

Comment: See also this question and its answers: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/29752/9781

Answer (score 3):

No language has a significant tendency to exclude palindromic syllables: if plarg and gralp are possible syllables, plalp and grarg are as well.

Comment: Hmm... at least *dissimilation* is an anti-palindromic process working against *plalp* and *grarg*

Comment: I think not, that is, dissimilation does not care about palindromicity, it cares about broader similarity. Place dissimilation for example may ban multiple velars in a syllable, which is distinct from an actual anti-palindrome principle. Place dissimilation more broadly targets *klaks", which is not a palindrome

Comment: Yes, it affects non-palindromes as well as palindromes. But the net effect is a deprecation of palindromes.

Comment: I would agree to a different question: are there any languages that deprecate syllables with similar consonants? That possibility is not "general" in languages, it is rare but not non-existent.